# How to take a photo using callee's phone camera in React Native like Facetime?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, photo, facetime, connectycube

**TLDR;
How do I make a photo service that does the following in a video calling app:**

1. caller presses button on phone1
2. callee's phone camera takes photo using phone2 camera
3. photo saved on caller's phone1

---

I am trying to make a photo service that works in an iOS project I'm building using React Native.

I used Connecty-Cube to make a video call service in the app, but now I want to add a button that allows the caller to take a photo of the callee.

I know I can just use `react-native-view-shot` to take a screenshot of the callee, but I want to take the photo using the callee's own phone camera.

I think FaceTime now has this functionality (they let FT users take live photos), but I haven't found any other apps that do this.

Does anyone have any pointers? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it using native code, you can easily bridge it to the JavaScript. That also can be more efficient than looking into some react-native plugin. More information you can get in [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) or [articles](https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-build-react-native-bridge-and-get-pdf-viewer-153109e42948)